Getting the error "“Cannot find reference ‘xbee’ in ´__init__.pyi´" when building micropython Code for Xbee3 Module
I am trying to make a simple script for my Xbee3 module, and I took the code (https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee-python/blob/master/examples/communication/ReceiveDataSample/ReceiveDataSample.py) and I am now getting the error “Cannot find reference ‘xbee’ in ´__init__.pyi´:
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice
Any idea what I need to change? I assume it’s micropython looking for the library in the wrong place or something akin to that?
enter image description here
enter image description here
I hope the above image gives any clarity to the issue.
I have tried messing around with the difference file paths and whatnot, but nothing seems to have worked.

That is just an issue with your IDE. See if the code actually works on the device.

You're in the wrong repository.  Those Python files are for Digi gateway products.
The XBee 3 products use MicroPython, and you'll want to make use of the xbee-micropython repository instead.  Per the README for that repo, you might also want to use the Digi XBee PyCharm IDE Plugin for development.
